# There is everything from X to Y

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Comment dirait-on la phrase suivante en français:

> In France there is everything from high mountains to incredible beaches.

Pourrait-on peut-être dire:

> En France il y a de tout, des hautes montagnes aux plages magnifiques

Comment: I think your translation is a very good one.

Comment: I'd say *from A to Z* (rather than *from X to Y*), since it encompasses everything (the whole alphabet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je pense que la version proposée dans la question est correcte. D'autres possibilités sont :

> **On/Il en a tout en France** : des plages magnifiques (jusqu')aux hautes montagnes.

> **On trouve tout en France** : des plages magnifiques (jusqu')aux hautes montagnes.

> **La France, on y trouve tout** : des plages magnifiques (jusqu')aux hautes montagnes.

Outre que le remplacement de la structure *il y a tout* par *on/il en a tout*, *on trouve tout*, notez les changement suivants :

- l'objet *en France* suit la phrase d'introduction
- logiquement, on va du point plus bas vers le point le plus haut (de la mer jusqu'aux sommets de montagnes)

Peut-être que les francophones pourraient nous dire si une des ces versions leur paraît plus naturelle.

Comment: ***En** France, on **y** trouve tout* ne me paraît pas idiomatique ou alors est de registre très relâché. On dirait plutôt: *En France, on trouve tout* ou *En France, on peut tout trouver*. Si tu veux garder le pronom *y*, tu peux aussi écrire: ***La** France, on y trouve tout [...]*.

Comment: @jlliagre merci !